# Open Windows date time settings from electron app

Tags: node.js, windows, electron

We have made an electron app where the user adds some files to our S3 bucket. If the date & time of the computer is incorrect then S3 upload fails. We would like to tell the user how to trouble shoot. Is it possible to launch the windows date time settings from node so that we can make it easier for the end user?

Comment: Run `control timedate.cpl`

Comment: can you elaborate how this is to be done using node?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
require('child_process').spawn('control', ['timedate.cpl'])
```

Answer (score 1):

In Windows 10 you might want to show the new Windows settings app instead. You can do this by [opening the correct URL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/launch-settings-app).

[image]

So to open the Date/Time setting you would use the following code:

```
const { shell } = require('electron')
shell.openExternal('ms-settings:dateandtime');
```

Comment: thanks... I don't have a windows 10 available, I will upvote your answer once I implement it